# Apple App Site Association File for Multiple Apps

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to set up an apple app site association file to support multiple app dealing with multiple URL patterns.

The file is deployed but is failing validation through Apple's App Search API Validation Tool. The tool doesn't give too much feedback on what is wrong with the file contents:

This is the contents of the file (with certain sensitive items replaced).

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [{
      "appIDs": [ "123456789.co.uk.my.app" ],
      "components":[{
        "/": "/some/path",
        "?": { "appName": "co.uk.my.app" }
      },
      {
        "/": "/some/other/path/step1"
      }]
    },
    {
      "appIDs": [ "123456789.co.uk.my.other.app" ],
      "components":[{
        "/": "/some/path",
        "?": { "appName": "co.uk.my.other.app" }
      },
      {
        "/": "/some/other/path/otherstep1"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Can anyone help us workout what is wrong with the file contents?